# XR Plugin Management Not Completing Install

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm having trouble getting the XR Plugin Management in settings to stop saying its downloading.

I tried the latest version.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue by sinning in unity.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers I found on the internet say that it's related to signing in. But if you're already signed in and still facing the issue, then follow the below steps.

1. Open the package manager window. Click Window > Package Manager
2. Now, you should see the Package Manager window opened. On this window, on the top bar, click Packages and select Unity Registry
3. Once done, you'll see a big list of items on the left side of the window. Scroll to the very bottom of the list where you'll find XR Plugin Management.
4. Choose XR Plugin Management and then install it by following the instructions.

This should solve your issue.